# PySpark array column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame containing a collection of books where each book can have one or more titles. Each title is classed as being either an original title, `OT` or an alternative title, `AT`. For simplicity, I'm omitting other title types. My validation needs to ensure that each book has exactly one `OT` title can have any number of `AT` titles.

What I'm trying to do is clean up the data so that:

- If a book has more than one `OT` title, keep the first and change the rest to `AT`
- If a book has no `OT` titles, change the first `AT` title to `OT`

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, col, struct

data = ([
  (1, 'Title 1', 'OT'),
  (1, 'Title 2', 'OT'),
  (2, 'Title 3', 'AT'),
  (2, 'Title 4', 'OT'),
  (3, 'Title 5', 'AT'),
])

schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("BookID", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("Title", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("Type", StringType(), True),
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df = df.groupby('BookID').agg(collect_list(struct(col('Title'), col('Type'))).alias('Titles'))

display(df)
```

It sounds like it should be easy but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using a udf like below but so far, that approach isn't working. I'm getting an error saying a `lambda cannot contain assignment`.

```
def process_titles(titles):
  x = list(filter(lambda t: t.Type == 'OT', titles))[1::]
  map(lambda t: t.Type = 'AT', x)
  
  return x

process_titles_udf = udf(lambda x: process_titles(x), titles)

df = df.withColumn('test', process_titles_udf('Titles'))
```

where the `udf` returns an object of type:

```
titles = ArrayType(StructType([ 
    StructField("Title", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("Type", StringType(), True)
  ]))
```

Comment: what is `titles` within `process_titles_udf = udf(lambda x: process_titles(x), titles)` ?

Comment: Sorry, that's a copy paste error. That would be a ArrayType() of a struct containing the Title and Type. I'll update the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, when you say "keep the first", you have to know that [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) is non-deterministic. So depending on your run, you may have different "first" OT.

If you want to continue with this non-deterministic behavior, here is your UDF :

```py
@udf(titles)
def process_titles(titles):
    OTs = [x for x in titles if x["Type"] == "OT"]  # Collect all OT types
    if OTs:
        OT = OTs[0]  # Keep the first OT as only OT if it exists
    else:
        OT = {
            "Title": titles[0]["Title"],
            "Type": "OT",
        }  # otherwise, use the first AT as OT

    ATs = [
        {"Title": x["Title"], "Type": "AT"} for x in titles if x["Title"] != OT["Title"]
    ]  # Transform all other titles as AT
    return [OT] + ATs


df.select("titles", process_titles(F.col("Titles"))).show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------+------------------------------+                 
|titles                        |process_titles(Titles)        |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|[[Title 1, OT], [Title 2, OT]]|[[Title 1, OT], [Title 2, AT]]|
|[[Title 5, AT]]               |[[Title 5, OT]]               |
|[[Title 3, AT], [Title 4, OT]]|[[Title 4, OT], [Title 3, AT]]|
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```